# Why do Computer Science degrees contain a high proportion of mathematics?

Tags: mathematics, computer-science

About 17 years ago I attended a top 10 UK university to study for a degree in Computer Science.

Mathematics had never been a particularly strong point for me. However I (just) had the required A-Level qualification to be accepted for the course without any issue.

After two terms I dropped out and switched to another top 10 UK University to study for an Information Technology degree. The reasons I dropped out from the former were simply because I found the Mathematical lectures unbelievably difficult. The university did not (in my opinion) provide good support to people who weren't strong in this area. However I also never understood why this level of mathematics was being taught in the first place.

I recently looked at some lecture notes provided on the former universities website for the current year. And sure enough, the level of complexity seems the same.

When I switched to doing an Information Technology degree part of my logic was that the outcome would be a more practical/useful set of skills to actually develop software, along with the logical thinking required (which in my view requires little mathematical knowledge). For me this has worked well as I've had a good career as a software developer since graduating. I've never found any of my work requires much maths, beyond that of a GCSE/A-level level of complexity.

Interestingly, looking on LinkedIn, a huge number of people at the former university went on to be software engineers or similar roles. The salaries at the organisations these people work seem commensurate to the role I am currently in.

Given this, I'm wondering what the end-goal and purpose of teaching that complex maths is on CS degrees? I understand some people will go into roles working with hardware, or even producing software where there are complex mathematical elements. But this seems to be in the minority - by a very big margin - in terms of what people actually end up doing. I have also spoken to people about careers they've gone into as opposed to just looking on LinkedIn etc.

It seems to me that CS courses are teaching skills which - whilst relevant - are not as relevant as they might once have been. If this is the case then why has nobody addressed it? It seems absurd.

My experience of this is based on two top 10 UK universities but having looked at some others (in the UK and USA) this seems to be a general case.

If people are going into roles which require that level of mathematical knowledge, what are those roles? Because I can't see a lot of evidence of this actually happening after people have graduated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99761/discussion-on-question-by-jimmy-why-do-computer-science-degrees-contain-a-high-p). Comments posted below this one should request clarification from the asker only (as there is no mechanism to move future discussion comments to chat, they risk being deleted)

Comment: Another guy cannot distinguish the difference between SDE and CS. SDE is for coding and engineering, while CS is more for doing research and science. The origin of *computer* is actually a *mathematical thought* but not a programmatic organism. But it's not your fault, people always do that. Lots of CS students don't have the ability and/or interest to go further in CS after undergraduate and then switch to SDE to develop stuff and make money. But it's not what CS means at the beginning.

Answer (score 153):

Oxford University’s overview of their CS degree says it all:

> Computer Science is about understanding computer systems and networks at a deep level. Computers and the programs they run are among the most complex products ever created; designing and using them effectively presents immense challenges. Facing these challenges is the aim of Computer Science as a practical discipline, and this leads to some fundamental questions:
>
> 1. How can we capture in a precise way what we want a computer system to do?
> 2. Can we mathematically prove that a computer system does what we want it to?
> 3. How can computers help us to model and investigate complex systems like the Earth’s climate, financial systems or our own bodies?
> 4. What are the limits to computing? Will quantum computers extend those limits?

In other words, the language of computer science is math, not C++. If you were looking for vocational training in computers then CS Is probably an inappropriate choice.

Comment: The part about vocational training could be more prominent. That's what the op seems to have been looking for.

Comment: "Will quantum computers extend those limits?". Lol, nope. Same computability / different computational complexity tho. Why do they use an open question to teaser students when the answer is essentially "Nope, computers can't do that".

Comment: @BlueWizard the *limits to computing* can also be taken as the *practical* limits. If a task would take eons with traditional computers, it is beyond those limits, despite being *theoretically* possible.

Comment: "If you were looking for vocational training in computers then CS is probably an inappropriate choice" - words I wish someone had told me at the *start* of my attempted degree in CS.

Comment: @BlueWizard, off topic, but classical computers running equation based computation for quantum systems quickly reaches the point of a hard limit, whereas quantum systems run directly on a quantum computer are actually viable. So to some extent, I'd say, yes, a quantum computer extends the limits of (some specialized) computing. Think material sciences, and others where macro behavior is deemed in part due to the quantum effects (like super conductors).

Comment: "In other words, the language of computer science is math, not C++"

I don't disagree with this, but I have yet to see a purely theoretical computer science course. Oxford's degree course teaches Scala as part of their imperative programming modules. Haskell for FP. Warwick teach Java and Haskell. These courses are *not* just designed for students to go on to do research, they all include some practical software engineering content alongside the theory.

Comment: @Adam Sure, and personally I find people from vocational courses have a way too strong focus on what's currently en vogue. I couldn't care less if my new employee has never seen Angular before, I want them to understand the basics. You'll have to learn a new framework/language all the time anyhow, if you understand the basics you can do that in a short time. I want them to understand concurrency, data structures, how computers work and the implications and all the other good stuff.

Comment: @Voo Agreed, definitely (and especially in the JS world it feels like we get a new framework to learn every 5 minutes). I think a healthy balance is important here: e.g. exposure to common programming language concepts by actually writing code within the course, learning version control concepts as well as the theoretical stuff: algorithm time complexity and data structures etc. I don't think I'd want to hire someone with _no_ prior practical programming experience regardless of their theoretical understanding.

Comment: @Adam Absolutely agreed. Honestly any CS program worth its salt should give their students exposure to many different programming paradigms. OOP, functional, logical (sure you'll never use prolog in practice, but there's valuable things to learn there). I mean in practice you do need to understand programming for those algorithm, compiler construction or machine learning courses anyhow, so I think that's not a big worry. If you can write a compiler in some language you surely learn the basics at least there ;)

Comment: @AdamWilliams What would you consider “purely theoretical”? The course I’m teaching currently (with the title “Intro to Algorithms and Models of Computation”) has no _programming_ whatsoever. (Also, “theoretical” is not the opposite of “useful”!)

Comment: @JeffE I assume students would do more than just that "course" though, right, in order to graduate and get their degree? NB: I think you can safely substitute "program" for course in my comments, because I'm a Brit. I did more than a few modules in my undergraduate degree course which contained no taught programming whatsoever - algorithm design, neural networks, linear algebra etc! These were included in a degree course *alongside* programming modules though, so there was still very much a mixture of the two. Indeed, the best practical programming modules built upon the theoretical modules.

Comment: Nowadays there is barely any area that is left out when it comes to mathematics. And CS involves a lot of that stuff especially if you're going for a higher degree. The reason is that the higher degree means getting more theoretical. This is due to the simple fact that higher degree (Masters, PhD) are directed towards people, who want to go into research, which requires a solid background in mathematics. Of course the real world is different (as usual) from what some academic people think so there are plenty of CS professionals with a Masters degree that keep away from research.

Comment: @Voo That's the reason I chose my degree course, at the University of York.  I came out with experience of 18 different languages across different paradigms.  I think only two modules that I took over four years that were not following on from a previous module shared a language.  The premise being that they teach us computer science and not a programming language.  I liked that premise.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you search the job boards at any standard company (bank, insurance provider, etc.) they want someone with a "Comp Sci degree, or equivalent". What they really want is someone with the "equivalent" which is an Information Systems degree. IS teaches you how to code and basic business process. The industry has never picked up on this so kids attempt to get CS degrees, rather than the more digestible IS degrees that are more relevant to typical business. You get a degree in IS to write code. You get a degree in CS to write the compiler that will build that code.

Comment: @RLH But then you really don't need a university to teach you programming. You can do that much more efficiently and better on your own with the available resources (as if any university would manage to stay on top of the new JavaScript framework every 6 months). Particularly if you learned the basics that underlie all those "new" things (if you understand monads you already understand all of LINQ, Optionals and in a way async/await). That's why I want someone with a Comp Sci degree.

Comment: "In other words, the language of computer science is math, not C++. If you were looking for vocational training in computers then CS Is probably an inappropriate choice." Perfect description of the difference. My *job* is a software developer, what I *am* is a scientist. A computer scientist.

Comment: @Voo There is a scale of learning in the direction of "pure" CS. Yes, you can learn much of that stuff on your own but a degree should give you entry-level validation. Whether you are a wiz-kid who picked up programming on his own or someone who got their start from within their college education, you need to learn the engineering basics to be an effective engineer. I learned that information in my IS degree, though it didn't go into great depths of those mechanics. I did learn basics of assembler and how the electronics work. It was just a survey, teaching principles and it suited me well.

Answer (score 49):

Well, you were in a computer **science** department and not in a computer **engineering** department. It would be a reasonable expectation that you would understand the fundamental mechanics of "computer stuff" and possibly continue your studies in research. I am not a computer scientist so examples may be limited here.

- cryptography: Beyond understanding RSA schemes there are many interesting research areas and applications. For example [elliptic curve cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography) uses serious level of mathematics or [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) uses encryption schemes imitating a mathematical concept of [morphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism) to process encrypted data without decryption (for example ordering numbers)
- communications theory: [Coding theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_theory) is heavily mathematical. It has some subfields that require more than a basic understanding of linear algebra. I have heard that research in [error correcting codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction) is quite non-trivial. Their main property is to detect and correct possible errors in communication. This is, likely, extra helpful for applications where communications are more likely to have errors. Consider space, polar or deep ocean exploration. On the theoretical side of coding theory, famously, someone used [algebraic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry) to show a theoretical upper bound for an invariant (don't remember its name) was as best as we could hope. (This would mean there are codes that give this exact value for the invariant as the upper bound predicts)
- Image recognition and machine learning also uses serious levels of linear algebra. Serious in the sense that the intuition of 3 dimensional vector spaces and ability to multiply some matrices would not be sufficient as you would be comparing vector spaces of *big number* dimensions. I am sure a more literate person would be more helpful on this point.
- [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) is a programming language based on a language mathematicians call [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory). I do not know benefits of using this Haskell but some people seem to love it. I would say however that category theory is very nontrivial. I would say an average student after completing an undergraduate degree in mathematics would have a very basic understanding of it. It is highly conceptual and its origins and most of its examples are usually graduate school material. Hence it would be really helpful to have a general mathematics background in order to relate what is going on.

Comment: Oh gosh, left a comment to the main question, just to immediately notice that your first sentence is basically my comment, emphasis and all :D

Comment: @penelope happens to best of us :)

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence. Do you really think "computer engineering" degrees are likely to involve *less* math? That does not fit my experience nor the common use of the word "engineering".

Comment: @CarlLeth Computer Engineering is "engineering" in the 19th century sense of the word, not the 21st.

Comment: @alephzero what specifically do you mean by that? (I personally have a grudge against calling what most people do computer engineering, since the repercussions for failure are so much lower than other fields of engineering)

Comment: @alephzero: Most Computer Engineering degrees I know of spawned off of Electrical Engineering (with more programming than pure EE, often some elements of Computer Science proper), which is *heavily* physics based. You may not need number theory, but you need a *lot* of math to handle the physics aspects of an Electrical or Computer Engineering degree degree. Software Engineering may require less math (and is barely engineering in the normal sense of the word), but computer engineering would not.

Comment: Nitpicking, but at least for my university, Computer Engineering is not Software Engineering. Echoing ShadowRanger, CE was much more hardware based

Comment: @llama I think the repercussions are field/industry dependent, as with other types of engineering!

Comment: @llama me too. I've never understood why some computer programmers like to call themselves engineers. Maybe it's to make themselves feel better about their chosen profession? Or maybe it's to make others think that computer programming is difficult and complicated? I shall continue to stubbornly refer to myself as a computer programmer, and annoy self-proclaimed "software engineers" by calling them programmers as well.

Comment: Engineering is the application of scientific principals to practical problems.  You need to be able to understand the science and do the maths in order to apply it.  This is as true for computer science and software engineering as it is for physics and mechanical or civil engineering.  If you're not doing maths and science in your computer work then you're probably a programmer rather than a software engineer.

Comment: Echo the others, computer engineering requires lots of mathematics, so the first sentence is odd. I'm an EE and regularly have computer engineers in my various classes. They take less math than an EE, but certainly a fair amount, even comparable to a computer science major. I think, as others mentioned, there is a misunderstanding of the term. Computer engineers are mostly EE's but with more of a focus on digital.

Comment: @llama Will you please consider what can happen when one of the physical components of a traffic lights system fails as opposed to what can happen when its software fails? Remember that in 2019 almost everything the "other" engineers build is controlled by software and the repercussions for failure are astronomic. Also, you might [enjoy this read](https://www.fastcompany.com/28121/they-write-right-stuff)

Comment: @Douwe hence the "most". Embedded systems, medical and the like are worthy of the title. Writing another app to create a market where one shouldn't exist and you ignore all safety concerns to sucker someone into throwing piles of money at you is not.

Comment: @llama It's not that those applications shouldn't be high quality, reliable, safe and with warranties. It's just that they _aren't_, because we kind of don't know how to do that. But that's the whole software development environment; how would bridges look if they were the result of a sales guy selling something impossible to do, and even the technically possible compromise having tenth of the budget you would need, while ten different people push their own global architectural decisions in the middle of the project, with most people not really knowing they're building a bridge?

Comment: @AaronF "Software Engineer" tends to pay better than "lowly programmer."  So in principle, I agree with you... but on my resume, best believe i'm a "Senior Software Engineer"

Comment: @EvilDogPie There's very little maths or science in software engineering. I'm fairly sure that term came about because "engineer" sounds more rigorous than "builder".

Comment: @AaronF: The truest sense of "engineer" is someone who uses their mind to create or design. A lot of the intro mechanical and computer engineering courses were wasted on me because I'd already had all that in software engineering. Software engineering includes establishing the exact problem, separating problem statements from proposed solutions that may suck, specifying exactly what product you will deliver to the client, preventing requirements creep, etc. It also includes working as a team, communicating with management, learning to accept stupid (err, different) practices on a project, etc.

Comment: Given the rule that "anything which calls itself a science probably isn't", the title of the field doesn't promise to solve anything here. Generally I'd say computer science departments support themselves by teaching programmers (basically technologists who operate machinery according to its manual), so they can pursue fun ideas like artificial intelligence and video games using whatever math methods are appropriate for mathematical formulations of their problems of interest. Occasionally they are able to completely annex the math topics by giving them cool new names.

Answer (score 33):

I made this mistake when choosing my major in college. Computer science is not really about computers, in the same way that math classes aren't really about using calculators or pencils and paper.

Modern computers are just a tool used to make computing (the true focus of computer science) easier and faster. This gets confusing because the things we compute would be incredibly time-consuming, or at least incredibly tedious, to do manually, so we almost always fall back on programming computers to do it for us. This means that you probably will do some programming (maybe a lot) for a CS degree, but this programming won't necessarily prepare you to create and deliver high-quality software.

My degree focused far more on studying models of computation and algorithms than on how to produce software. This is still helpful in software development, as knowing efficient algorithms for various problems is good when you're constrained by time or memory capacity. However, it does mean that a CS degree will not necessarily include training for software development, as that is not the primary focus.

Comment: There is a famous quote in one of the greatest programming textbooks of all time, that computer science is about computers about the same as astronomy is about telescopes. (Imagine, astronomy was called "telescope science".) The analogy is even more apt than some people realize, because (just like with computers), astronomers aren't even the ones that are researching, designing, engineering, building, and studying telescopes. So, if you are interested in *telescopes*, astronomy is the wrong field for you to be in, and the same thing applies to computers.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Oldest source I can find is "Computer Science is not about computers in the same sense that physics is not really about particle accelerators, and biology is not about microscopes and Petri dishes" - Hal Abelson, 1986.

Comment: I really wish we'd make a push to rename the field to "Computing Science" instead.

Comment: @orlp It's usually referred to as "information and computing technology" where I'm from :) Not that it really helps, since it's used for both science and engineering anyway :)

Comment: My degree (from Stirling University, back in 1992) WAS called "Computing Science"! Which makes total sense. I was/am only average at mathematics, but some parts have been invaluable  in my software development career - e.g. understanding sets helped me immensely in becoming very good with databases.

Comment: @orlp I don't think that would help. First, nobody's going to notice the difference between computer science and -ing science; second, it sounds too much like scientific computing; third, it still has the "comput-" part, so people sill misunderstand it in the same way; fourth, the "science" part is mostly wrong.

Answer (score 22):

Here in Germany, the field "Computer Science" is called "Informatik", which, according to the [etymology of the term "computer science"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science#Etymology), is either a contraction of the words "information" and "automatic", or of "information" and "mathematics"...

---

As others have already pointed out, there are many *direct* connections between computer science and mathematics, on different levels:

- Linear algebra is important for many forms of modern machine learning: Neural networks are essentially just large matrices - or conversely, a [machine learning system is just a large pile of linear algebra](https://xkcd.com/1838/) ;-). Another (maybe obvious) field is that of 3D computer graphics: All the special effects in movies are just a bunch of triangles and the answer to the question of what happens when light hits a surface
- Calculus is essential for complexity theory (which analyzes the running time of algorithms), numerical analysis (which is required for estimating the error of approximations), and many other topics
- General (or "abstract") algebra is about *structures* and *rules* (or operations) within these structures. There is a strong (and in my opinion, severely underrated) connection of this to *Object-oriented programming*.
- Logic is an important basis for what you might call "low-level" programming, even though the connection between knowing that you can safely turn an `if (!(a || b))` into an `if (!a && !b)` and formal propositional logic may not be obvious. Of course, far beyond that, there are even logic-based programming languages like [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog).
- ...

There are many more *direct* connections, meaning that you come in touch with a certain branch of mathematics when you *apply* computer science in practice.

But there are also *indirect* connections: Mathematics is a language for good descriptions. Mathematics teaches a form of clarity, rigorousness, and preciseness that is *necessary* in order to manage the complex IT systems that we are dealing with nowadays. What may be perceived as "nitpicking" elsewhere is crucial in order to make sure that these systems operate in the way that we expect them to operate. When you have ever written something like a software specification, and missed a corner case, then you know: People will find that corner case. And they will hate you for missing it...

---

However, from a practical point, I totally agree: The things that most people with a degree in computer science nowadays have to do in their jobs are totally unrelated to mathematics (and also totally unrelated to programming, for that matter). And it's somehow a pity to imagine that many students frustratedly drop out of their university courses (which they *might* have entered with wrong expectations about the subject) due to their bad math grades. These people could otherwise have been great at what they *actually* had to do in their jobs.

---

My view here may be a bit narrow, because I only know the situation in Germany - even though I observed the developments in this area for >20 years now. But you referred to the UK, so the following may still be relevant. I read this quite a while ago, and it somehow stuck in my mind. It's a quote from an [essay "On the fact that the Atlantic Ocean has two sides"](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD06xx/EWD611.html), by Edsger W. Dijkstra (yes, [**this** Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)) :

> The first series of machines —that of the singletons— was mainly developed in the USA shortly after the World War II, while a ruined continental Europe had neither the technology, nor the money, to start building computers: the only thing we could do was thinking about them. Therefore it is not surprising that many US Departments of Computer Science are offsprings of Departments of Electrical Engineering, whereas those in Europe started (later) from Departments of Mathematics (of which they are often still a part). This different heritage still colours the departments, and could provide an acceptable explanation that in the USA Computing Science is viewed more operationally than in Europe.

That could explain it, to *some* extent, at least...

Comment: In spanish is 'informática' , as in 'ciencias de la informatica', and just like in german, there is a clear difference too.

Answer (score 12):

There are two aspects of this and one of them is usually forgotten. The usual reason is that some parts of CS are dependent on knowing mathematics and how to use it. The [answer of Boaty Mcboatface](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/138169/75368) mentions some of them. But not all of CS is like that and those working, say, in Human Factors or UI development probably use the math they learned much less than those studying algorithms or encryption.

But the other aspect is also important. The study of CS is enhanced from knowing the way in which mathematicians think and work - the mathematical way of thinking - not just from having facts at your fingertips. Mathematicians tend to be analytical and precise, depending on clear statements and logical demonstration. This way of looking at problems and stating solutions is of use to a computer scientist.

But there are a lot of other things that are also important in CS, so a broad education is valued, not just a math background. After all, many of us try to solve problems for people, not just for others in our own field. So, while mathematics is often useful in helping to develop the *how* of some solution, it is less useful in knowing *why* some program should or should not be developed.

---

*Good mathematicians* are also very creative, though that quality is widely shared with people of other fields. But becoming good in mathematics takes some work. Both depth and breadth are needed.

Answer (score 5):

**Computer science is the *study* of computers and the underlying theory.
Software development is the *use* of computers to... develop software.**

This underlying theory is largely math... so by studying it, you are essentially studying (a small subsection of) math.  Thus, there is a high proportion of math involved.

**To your underlying question, however, academia is an often confusing and misunderstood place.**

Only recently have people started realizing that a college degree is in many cases unnecessary, and in fact may be detrimental to your career path - in many fields besides just computer science.  (i.e. 4+ years of tangentially related studying vs. 4+ years of job experience)

For software development in particular, computer science is really only a tangentially related field.

If CS 201 was indeed unnecessary for CS 305, it would not be a prerequisite.  If it did not contain useful knowledge, indeed it would likely be quickly cut out of the curriculum, or relegated to an elective.  It is certainly absurd to think that universities would teach useless things for an extended period of time.

**Math is very useful in computer science - regularly less so in software development.**

Comment: Actually, I'd say that math is used constantly in software development; it's just math that's well-developed enough that most developers use it intuitively, rather than having to have a formal understanding of it. Most programs include at least one function, but a "function," is actually, like zero or negative numbers, a fairly sophisticated mathematical idea, not something that people have always known and understood.

Comment: A "function" in the mathematical sense, and a "function" in the programming sense are only distantly related.  Learning about mathematical functions really doesn't help with programming functions.

Comment: @MartinBonner It's not that distant. Make the function immutable (and if you're feeling adventurous, take one argument) and you're golden. For bonus points, add proper lambda calculus. The main difference is that most programmers don't really do anything with functions beyond invoking them :)

Comment: @Luaan Well yes, but *most* computer functions are not immutable, and have side effects.

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes, but many software engineers will also tell you it's a really bad idea :P It's one of those things that makes software development far less reliable and far more complex than it has any need to be, for essentially no benefit - it's a massive source of accidental complexity.

Comment: @Martin Yes, but what is the relationship between the two? And how can we change program functions to be closer to mathematical functions? That's math. Why would we make such a change? Because we can then use more of our mathematical tools to help show (even sometimes prove) that the function does what we hope it does. And that addresses a core part of programming: how do we ensure our programs are doing what we hope they do, i.e., are correct? This is all part of a point that Dijkstra was making (not so very successfully) forty years ago.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson The answers to your questions are, respectively, "Programmers don't care", "Programmers don't care" and "We wouldn't, because programmers don't care" and "testing".

Comment: @David You're correct that those are the _common_ answers. I hope you're not saying that those are _good_ answers! As for the last, [Dijkstra yet again](https://github.com/dot-home/unfortunate/blob/master/share/fortune/dijkstra): "The first moral of the story is that program testing can be used very effectively to show the presence of bugs but never to show their absence." (We're now only a couple of years from the 50th anniversary of [EWD303](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD03xx/EWD303.html), yet still refusing to face the same problems. Sigh.)

Comment: It is not a new thing to be skeptical of the value of a degree in computer science. It has become particularly obvious every time technology goes through rapid change and the CS degree content becomes outdated. Other professions like engineering are a lot more stable. And there the classes which teach the needed skills require years of fundamental prerequisites (like years of math going from basic to advanced), whereas you can take a programming course as a freshman without any prerequisites.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's Computer SCIENCE, and pretty much all science depends on math.  Sure, there are things you can do with computers that don't involve much math (if any), like (AFAIK) implementing something like StackExchange.  And you're quite correct that a degree in Information Technology or something similar would probably qualify you for a lot of jobs, without the need to learn anything beyond basic arithmetic.

OTOH, there are a lot of jobs that do involve applying (what might from your POV be) fairly complicated math.  For instance, what I'm doing these days involves applying numerical solutions to a particular class of partial differential equations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_equation ).  Probably 90% of my career has involved similar levels of math.  So it's all in what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Because *computing* science (see below), and even computer
programming, *is* applied mathematics.

Ed Dubinsky, a mathematics educator who was once a professional
programmer himself, [has said](http://www.math.kent.edu/~edd/PROCESSFUNC.pdf):

> A person's mathematical knowledge is her or his tendency to respond
>   to certain kinds of perceived problem situations by constructing,
>   reconstructing and organizing mental processes and objects to use in
>   dealing with the situations.

At a slightly less general level, consider what mathematics is. You choose or
create a language in which you can express certain ideas and then do
symbolic manipulation according to a set of rules you've also chosen
or created to come up with to create more valid statements in that
language according to those rules. If you're not careful to do this
correctly, you may come out with invalid statements. The results you
come up with may have some sort of application in the "real world"
(e.g., I can use the language and rules of "integers" to help keep
track of what people owe me and I owe them) or may be just work to
help you better understand how you can use the language and rules and
how they can be helpful to you in further use of them.

In many parts of mathematics we use particular symbols called
"numbers" and have a large library of oft-shared rules and languages
related to this, but there are other areas of mathematics that don't
use numbers at all (e.g., category theory), or, though they can be
applied to numbers, are not really about numbers *per se* (group
theory, algebraic structures, many more).

Even before you get into the study or use of particular algorithms and
the like, writing a computer program is basically what I described
above. Many of the "simplest" concepts in computer programming that we
use every day, such as the idea of a function, are purely mathematical
concepts.

Now as you've seen, it's perfectly possible to attack real-world
problems with these mathematical tools in a non-rigorous way and get
useful results. Typically the results will not be truly correct (i.e.,
your programs will have bugs), but they will be "correct enough" to do
the job. (For a well written program in industry, you may never even
encounter the situations that would demonstrate that it's incorrect.)
That's what the discipline of engineering is: getting results that
work well enough in the real world at acceptable cost.

But even when you're doing engineering, much of what you do works well
only because someone has gone and done enough mathematical heavy
lifting to give you concepts and tools that you can use to do this.
You may not have a really good understanding of what a function or a
relation is, but your programming language or database system works
because somebody did figure those out.

And the people who did that work are the computing scientists.

All this has been known and seriously contemplated for a long time. I
think it's particularly well demonstrated by a comment in Peter
Landin's classic 1966 paper ["The Next 700 Programming
Languages"][landin66]:

> The most important contribution of LISP was not in list processing
>   or storage allocation or notation, but in the logical properties
>   lying behind the notation. here ISWIM makes little improvement
>   because, except for a few minor details, LISP left none to make.
>   There are two equivalant ways of stating these properties.
>
> (a) LISP simplified the equivalence relations that determine the
>   extent to which pieces of a program can be interchanged without
>   affecting the outcome.
>
> (b) LISP brought the class of entities that are denoted by
>   expressions a programmer can write nearer to those that arise in
>   models of physical systems and in mathematical and logical systems.

If you understand this (which probably requires some at least
intuitive understanding of the of the lambda calculus or similar), you
probably realize that a lot of the problems we deal with today are
still the same basically mathematical problems that were being
investigated back in the '60s when we were first seriously
investigating what a "programming language" really is and means.

**On Working Programs**

One can also look at this from the more narrow viewpoint of, "I just
want to write a program and make sure it works." Even here this
becomes math if you take as a constraint "I really do want to, as best
I can, make sure it works." Dijkstra's [EWD303](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD03xx/EWD303.html), "On the Reliability
of Programs," makes this argument in detail. His summary:

> Reliability concerns force us to restrict ourselves to
>   intellectually manageable programs. This faces us with the questions
>   "But how do we manage complex structure intellectually? What mental
>   aids do we have, what patterns of thought are efficient? What are
>   the intrinsic limitations of the human mind that we had better
>   respect?" Without knowledge and experience, such questions would be
>   very hard to answer, but luckily enough, our culture harbours with a
>   tradition of centuries an intellectual discipline whose main purpose
>   it is to apply efficient structuring to otherwise intellectually
>   unmanageable complexity. This discipline is called "Mathematics". If
>   we take the existence of the impressive body of Mathematics as the
>   experimental evidence for the opinion that for the human mind the
>   mathematical method is, indeed, the most effective way to come to
>   grips with complexity, we have no choice any longer: we should
>   reshape our field of programming in such a way that their methods of
>   understanding become equally applicable, for there are no other
>   means.

**On "Computing Science" versus "Computer Science"**

Some amongst us, including the [University of Alberta](https://www.ualberta.ca/computing-science/about-the-department/department-history), find the
more common name of the discipline slightly misleading and instead
prefer to call it *Computing* Science. As Keith Smillie said in
["Computing Science at the University of Alberta, 1957 -
1993"](https://web.archive.org/web/20151019055830/webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~smillie/CompSci/DeptHist1993rev.pdf):

> The choice of the name "computing science" instead of the more
>   common "computer science" was deliberate in order to indicate that
>   computing rather than computers was to be the foundation of the
>   discipline.

Thinking about what we are wrangling with as "computing" rather than
"computers" way may help you remember that all the software running
the world today is much more dependent on the mathematical tools we
use to be able to effectively and accurately model our problems and
the world than on the hardware on which it runs.

Comment: And to add to the terminology fun, we have the professional society for researchers and practitioners that calls itself the **[Association for Computing Machinery](https://www.acm.org/)**. (Despite its title, I believe most of its members are actually _human beings_.)

Comment: @jeffB The main difference between computing machines and humans is that humans are more complex and therefore more easily distracted.

Answer (score 2):

Here in Poland there is a lot of math specialist, but very little IT specialists available at universities (due to horrid salary difference I guess).
So you end up having way too many mathematicians who need something to do - and bam, you just over-burden the IT studies with math, raw, unprocessed math, without showing you connections and uses in computer sciences.
And after 5 years of university you get students who had 5 years of analysis, 2 semesters of geometry, another semesters of statistics and can barely program in c++, Ada and some java or python if they were lucky.

Comment: I don't see the problem really. The skillsets of computer scientist and C++ programmers overlap to a degree, but they're far from identical. It appears that Poland is lacking vocational training in IT. You don't exactly need a PhD in CompSci to use C++.

Comment: @MSalters More importantly, a PhD in CompSci probably doesn't help you use C++ all that much (beyond perhaps getting the sensible idea of running away from C++, fast :D ). You get plenty of benefits from advanced courses in algorithmisation and all sorts of math, but they apply to all programming languages equally - they happen at a different level of abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key thing that is missing here is the broader point. In the majority of cases, University degrees do not provide **training**, they provide **education**. Thus a university degree teaches, in general, not how to do a particular job, but how to think, analyse and assess knowledge.

The vast majority of all students who study for a degree will not go on to a job that directly uses the knowledge taught in a degree. Students with one of our degrees might be more employable as a side benefit, but it is not the primary goal of most degrees. (there are exceptions to this like medicine or law).

Answer (score 1):

All of these answers fail to describe something essential:

Most jobs with writing code are doing the equivalent of **fabrication**, not *engineering*, and certainly not *science*.

If this doesn’t make immediate sense, it may help to understand the equivalent when working with classical materials.  A scientists would study metallurgy and how to make new alloys. In engineering, one would evaluate how large of a girder can be made from the material, or the limits of wear and tear in scenarios. Fabricators would receive the material in the form of pipes, which they assemble to fit the means of things like a kitchen, a bathroom, or maybe a whole house.

A technician, like someone that works HVAC or automotive, would take pre-constructed subsystems and fit them together with a bit of adjustment using fabrication.

Most careers that involve code are doing fabrication, or technician work.  Increasingly, software jobs are technician roles. The jobs require continual awareness of new libraries and frameworks, and how to ensure their ease of assembly and configuration.

But that’s not what computer science schools are out there to teach. **You don’t go to oxford, or any other Ivy League university to learn how to be a fabricator**.  If you went to a school like that, and learned you don’t have the appetite or ability for science..... that’s the dice.

> The same thing goes for Fine Arts schools with concept studio core curricula.

It doesn’t mean that programs teaching legitimate science should do less of that.

Answer (score 0):

Computer science involves efficient problem-solving process, which can be attained through applied mathematics courses. At least, that's what employers and recruiters look for. Most of the time, the algorithm frameworks are based on math logic. If you don't plan to use the CS degree as a designer, an engineer, or other application-approach, you don't need to employ as much math.